# F# "this rule will never be matched" expression in a NOT recursive function

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have such a function:

```
let RotateFace (face: int, turns: int) =
    match face with
        | upperface -> 
            TiltCube(2)
            TwistCube(turns)
            TiltCube(2)
        | leftface -> 
            TiltCube(3)
            TwistCube(turns)
            TiltCube(1)
        | frontface -> 
            TurnCube(1)
            TiltCube(3)
            TwistCube(turns)
            TiltCube(1)
            TurnCube(3)
        | rightface -> 
            TiltCube(1)
            TwistCube(turns)
            TiltCube(3)
        | backface -> 
            TiltCube(3)
            TwistCube(turns)
            TiltCube(1)
        | downface -> 
            TurnCube(3)
            TiltCube(3)
            TwistCube(turns)
            TiltCube(1)
            TurnCube(1)
        | _ -> ()
```

I have a "this rule will never be matched" problem on my cases "'upperface', 'leftface', 'frontface', 'rightface', 'backface', 'downface', and '_'.".

I've looked this link;

[f# match expression - "rule will never be matched"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984535/f-match-expression-rule-will-never-be-matched)

but to be honest I didn't understand what should I do with my case.

Comment: What's `upperface`, `leftface`, etc?

Comment: let LEFTFACE = 0, let UPPERFACE = 4

Comment: yusuf you should add ALL relevant code into your question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't match against a variable, I mean you can but if you do so what would happen is that the variable will be bound to that value and it seems to me that's not what you are trying to do, otherwise the first case in your code will "eat" all other cases and that's why the following rules will never be matched.

You can either match with a condition:

```
let RotateFace (face: int, turns: int) =
    match face with
        | x when x = upperface -> 
            TiltCube(2)
            TwistCube(turns)
            TiltCube(2)
```

or declare `upperface` and the other variables as constants by using the [literal attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353581.aspx):

```
[<Literal>]
let Upperface  = 4

let RotateFace (face: int, turns: int) =
    match face with
        | Upperface -> 
            TiltCube(2)
            TwistCube(turns)
            TiltCube(2)
```

Comment: I was playing with `[<Literal>]` and VS still gives the same errors. Weird.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Did you switch to uppercase identifiers?

Comment: wow. That made the trick. Why is uppercase required for `[<Literal>]`?

Comment: OK, I think I found an answer. It's not `Literal`, it's pattern matching that needs them to be uppercased: *In pattern matching expressions, identifiers that begin with lowercase characters are always treated as variables to be bound, rather than as literals, so you should generally use initial capitals when you define literals.*

Comment: Yes, I was going to point you to the spec in section 7.2, but you already found it. Why did they decide that it's another story.

Comment: But Marcin, in this case this warning is encountered: Uppercase variable identifiers should not generally be used in patterns, and may indicate a misspelt pattern name.

Comment: Another option would be to make those values an enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, [Gustavo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27695821/4191347) is the correct answer to the question and shows some nice details about pattern matching. In your case, though, instead of matching with integers, you might want to match with [discriminated union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) cases.

In other words, the variable `face` could have the type `Face` instead of `int`:

```
type [<RequireQualifiedAccess>] Face =
    Front | Back | Top | Bottom | Left | Right
```

The `RequireQualifiedAccess` attribute means that you have to write `Face.Front` instead of just `Front`. You can leave it out if the cases never mean anything else. Anyway, using the definition above, `RotateFace` becomes:

```
let RotateFace (face, turns: int) =
    match face with
    | Face.Top -> 
        TiltCube(2)
        TwistCube(turns)
        TiltCube(2)
    | Face.Left -> 
        TiltCube(3)
        TwistCube(turns)
        TiltCube(1)
    // and so on
```

This way, you also don't need the `_ -> ()` case, because the compiler knows that your pattern match handles all the faces.

*Ohhhhhh! You are building a 3x3x3 Rubick's Cube solver with Lego Mindstorms and F#! Finally I see what connects these questions.* :D